# How do I calculate the electron density of a gold atom?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, atomic-physics, orbitals, elements

I have to calculate the electron density of a gold atom. As far as I know, it is given by $\rho=e|\psi|^2$ if $\psi$ is the wave function of the electrons. The only way I know for calculate the wave function $\psi$ is the Hartree-Fock method, but with gold I would have 79 kinetic terms and $\dfrac{79*(79-1)}{2}=3081$ exchange terms. I am sure someone came up a more clever idea.

Can anyone point out a way to solve this problem?

It looks like some more details are needed. My goal is to calculate the scattering amplitude of electrons impinging on a test mass of gold. In order to do this, I have to solve the differential equation:

$$-\dfrac{\hbar}{2m} \dfrac{1}{r^2} \dfrac{d}{dr} \left( r^2\dfrac{d}{dr}R_l(r) \right) + \dfrac{\hbar}{2m} \dfrac{l(l+1)}{r^2} R_l(r) - \left( -\dfrac{Ze^2}{r} + V_{ext}(r) \right)R_l(r)=E \,R_l(r)$$

where the potential $V_{ex}(r)\propto \rho(r)$ where $\rho(r)$ is the electron density of the gold atom.

Comment: Without more information about why/to what level of precision you need to calculate this (is it homework?), it is difficult to be sure, but it sounds like you could benefit by reading up about [Density Functional Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_functional_theory). There are existing libraries that you could use to do this (rolling your own is likely to be non-trivial).

Typically you'd setup some sort of a variational problem, where you need to find a density matrix for the system (in this case, a gold atom's) that minimises its energy.

Comment: @MartinC. It is not homework it is work. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @MartinC. see my edit I added some details of my final goal.

Comment: I see. In that case I am not sure that DFT is the appropriate tool...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Hartree-Fock method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartree%E2%80%93Fock_method) is a numerical method for getting
approximate solutions for the Schrödinger equation in a multi-electron atom.
It tries to model the mutual electrical repulsion *and*
Pauli's exclusion principle between the electrons.
As results it predicts the electron shells (for the ground state
and for excited states) quite well.
It was famous for the big computer-power needed for the calculations.

A simpler approach is the [Thomas-Fermi model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas%E2%80%93Fermi_model).
It models the electrons in a semi-classical way as moving in the
*same common* potential, which in turn is created by the charge
density of all electrons.
This approximation is bad for atoms with only a few electrons,
but it gives a reasonable result for atoms with many electrons
(like the gold atom with 79 electrons).
Of course this model doesn't predict the electron shells,
but instead gives a broader view glossing over these "details".

The image below compares the electron density of the Neon
atom (i.e. 10 electrons) as calculated by Hartree-Fock and Thomas-Fermi
model.

[image]
<sub>(image from [Analytic model of a multi-electron atom](https://www.groundai.com/project/analytic-model-of-a-multi-electron-atom/6))</sub>